# Find out org id

Tags: login, id, org, environment

What are the ways to find out my org id?

[Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006019&type=1) is a way I found.

> 1. Log In to the Salesforce Help and Training Portal.
> 2. Scroll to the Support & Services tile and view your Organization ID.

I have hard time following the steps.

At first I go to over [here](https://help.salesforce.com/home). Then I go to login in the top right corner and select with Salesforce.

[image]

I provide correct username and password, but when I click to login I am redirected back to [here](https://help.salesforce.com/home) and not logged in.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

I checked that username and password are correct by logging into salesforce account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you are logging in to the "Help & Training" portal instead of your Org.

To be able to view your Organization Id, login to your Salesforce instance either *test.salesforce.com* or *login.salesforce.com* depending on if you are logging in to Sandbox or Production.

Once logged in, you navigate through these steps to get your Organization Id.

- Go to Setup
- Go to Company Information (under Company Setting menu in LEX or Company Profile in Classic)
- You will find the Organization Id under *Salesforce.com Organization ID* field

  [image]